# Formatting a datetime from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have date in this format in JavaScript:

`Fri Jan 27 2012 08:01:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

I want to format the date to `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` .

Comment: [moment](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 2):

With this:

```
//Formats d to MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss format
function formatDate(d){
  function addZero(n){
     return n < 10 ? '0' + n : '' + n;
  }

    return addZero(d.getMonth()+1)+"/"+ addZero(d.getDate()) + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + 
           addZero(d.getHours()) + ":" + addZero(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + addZero(d.getMinutes());
}

var str = 'Fri Jan 27 2012 08:01:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
var date = new Date(Date.parse(str));
var formatted = formatDate(date);
alert(formatted);  //alerts "01/26/2012 22:31:31"
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate it as a string like this:

```
var date = new Date();
var month = (date.getMonth()+1) > 9 ? (date.getMonth()+1) : "0" + (date.getMonth()+1);
var day = (date.getDate()+1) > 9 ? (date.getDate()+1) : "0" + (date.getDate()+1);
var hours = (date.getHours()) > 9 ? (date.getHours()) : "0" + (date.getHours());
var minutes = (date.getMinutes()) > 9 ? (date.getMinutes()) : "0" + (date.getMinutes());
var seconds = (date.getSeconds()) > 9 ? (date.getSeconds()) : "0" + (date.getSeconds());

var dateString = 
    month + "/" + 
    day + "/" + 
    date.getFullYear() + " " + 
    hours + ":" + 
    minutes + ":" + 
    seconds;
```

And always remember, javascript Date's months are zero-based

the Method `.toLocaleString` returns a similar result but with month and day switched like this:

```
dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wnQ3/3/)

Comment: Important to note for the OP here is that Months in JS are zero-based, thus the `date.getMonth()+1`.

Comment: Yep, should have noted that, I gonna edit answer ;)

Comment: is this the only way?any predefinefunctions

Comment: There is only that function `.toLocaleString` but you need the month first, right?

Comment: You could use a library like Moment.js which contains a custom format function.

Comment: I tried the above code it comes like M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss format.I need MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Comment: I correct that, give me a second

Comment: I added some lines that check if there needs a zero to beconcatenated and updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        var date = new Date();
        var month = date.getMonth()+ 1;
        var dateString =  month + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
        console.log(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) is a plugin for datetimeformat

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log($.format.date("Fri Jan 27 2012 08:01:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    });
```